# How to prevent .initial:n from setting keys before \ProcessKeysOptions is called?

Tags: expl3, programming, l3keys

I am writing myself a package and I want to use imakeidx as a dependency.
However, I don't want to make it a hard dependency, and so I was going to add a package option to disable to automatic loading of imakeidx.

However, I am unable to get this to work, as imakeidx is always getting loaded.

Looking at the debugging `\iow_term:n` statements, it looks like the `true` code is executed during `\keys_define:nn` due to the `.initial:n` statement. Later the `false` code is then executed when `\ProcessKeysOptions` gets called.

However, without the `.initial:n` statement, imakeidx does not get loaded if the option is not specified.

Is there a way to set a default key value that doesn't execute the code until `\ProcessKeysOptions` is called?

```tex
\RequirePackage{ expl3 }
\ProvidesExplPackage {mypkg} {2023-06-29} {1.0.0} { My package }
\RequirePackage { l3keys2e }

\keys_define:nn { mypkg } {
    imakeidx .choice: 
  , imakeidx / true  .code:n = { \iow_term:n { imakeidx~True  } \RequirePackage { imakeidx } }
  , imakeidx / false .code:n = { \iow_term:n { imakeidx~False } }
  , imakeidx / unknown .code:n = {
      \__msg_kernel_error:nnx { kernel } { boolean-values-only } { #1 }
    }
  , imakeidx .usage:n = { preamble }
  , imakeidx .default:n = { true }
  , imakeidx .initial:n = { true }
}
\ProcessKeysOptions { mypkg }
\endinput
```

And in the main document:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[imakeidx=false]{mypkg}
\begin{document}
\index{imakeidx should not be loaded}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should post the full MWE code for people to be able to test `mypkg`

Comment: @daleif should now be runnable

Comment: Given that both `\iow_term:n`'s gets executed I expect that one loads packages later (aka checks if the key is true)

Comment: define your key so that it sets a boolean, and then load the package after the processing of the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. At the spot you use `.initial:n` you're setting those keys.

If you want to set specific options only after the package options were evaluated you can do so using `\keys_set:nn`.

NB: You don't need to use `l3keys2e` anymore, key=value option parsing got integrated into the LaTeX kernel. If you drop the package and use `\ProcessKeyOptions[mypgk]` you'll get the same and even more niceties from LaTeX.

In your specific case, in which you want to load a package, use

```
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
     imakeidx .bool_set:N = \l__mypkg_imakeidx_bool,
     imakeidx .usage:n = load
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg]

\bool_if:NT \l__mypkg_imakeidx_bool { \RequirePackage {imakeidx} }
```